# Apache reverse proxy with IIS SNI returning 404

Tags: apache-2.4, iis-8.5

I use an Apache reverse proxy to a number of IIS sites. When using IIS 8.5 with SNI I'm getting 404s back when I take an app pool and site offline.

Traditionally there would be no response and the connection would time out. I'd get a 503 back from mod proxy, which I'd use to display an error page. How do I change the behavior in IIS to not respond in these cases to keep this working, or find a better way to address this?

EDIT: I can get back the old behavior if I stop *all* of the sites in IIS, but this isn't a real fix to the issue.